# Django: Select object contains all keywords

Tags: python, sql, django

Here is the db looks like:

```
id | Post    |  tag
 1 | Post(1) |  'a'
 2 | Post(1) |  'b'
 3 | Post(2) |  'a'
 4 | Post(3) |  'b'
```

And here is the code of the module

```
class PostMention(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is the code of search,

```
def findPostTag(tag):
    keywords=tag.split(' ')
    keyQs = [Q(tag=x) for x in keywords]
    keyQ = keyQs.pop()
    for i in keyQs:
        keyQ &= i
    a = PostMention.objects.filter(keyQ).order_by('-id')
    if not a:
        a=[]
    return a
```

(this code does not work correctly)

I withdraw the tags and save each as one row in the database. Now I want to make a search function that the user can input more than one keywords at the same time, like `'a b'`,  and it will return 'Post(1)'. I searched for some similar situations, but seems all about searching for multi keywords in **one row** at the same time, like using `Q(tag='a') & Q(tag='b')`, it will search for the tag that equals to both 'a' and 'b'(in my view), which is not what I want (and get no result, obviously). So is there any solution to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Usually it is better understandable if you post actual code. Like the relevant part of your Django Model, and maybe the query your have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this cases, django provides, `ManyToManyField`, to  work correctly you must to use:

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name='Tags')

class Post(models.Model): #your model
    title = models.CharField(verbosone_name = 'Title')
    post_tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, verbose_name='Choice your tags')
```

So you'll choice many tags to your post

Comment: I will continue trying when I get up... Too sleepyyyyy today, but thanks, I think it will work awesomely.